# Flutter alertDialog does not show semantics when triggered in front of the webview

Tags: flutter, webview, android-alertdialog, voiceover, talkback

I am calling showDialog with AlertDialog() and I want buttons to have their own semantics as well as title and description. It works fine when there is no webview below it, but when I have InAppWebview below it then semantics are ignored and not clickable when using talkback or voiceover. Any ideas how to solve issue?